# mongodb insert in meteor.js doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a meteor.js project running and I'm trying to insert a row into a projects collection from the command prompt for mongodb. However, the insert just shows ellipses for a really long time, till is cancel it with ctrl+c. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There isn't any errors.

I'm new to mongo and I'm not sure how to start troubleshooting this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got some angled double apostrophe characters in there. Try replacing the apostrophe's around "Story of the Bastard Frog" with " characters (and don't forget the first one of the code "bastardFrog")

The ellipsis usually only appear when the input is not complete yet (e.g. when omitting the final parenthesis)